# How to deal with bright reflections in paper sheets detection in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'm making a document scanner for a college project, my code work quite well for any of the uniform lighted images. However I came across issues detecting images with even a little amount of light reflections (or too much light) on the background surface.

I first tried different simple codes I found online, then using different morphological operation, with the result that now my code is a little messy and inaccurate.
Here's the code:

```
def scanner(img):    
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))    
    image = cv2.imread(img)    
    original = image.copy()    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)       
    contrast = clahe.apply(gray)    
    blurred = cv2.medianBlur(contrast, 21)
    canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 0, 70)    
    dialated = cv2.dilate(canny, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5)), iterations = 3)    
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dialated, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5,5),np.uint8),iterations = 10)    
    contimage, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)    
    contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
    target = None

    for c in contours:
        p = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.09 * p, True)

        if len(approx) == 4:
            target = approx
            cv2.drawContours(image, [target], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            break

    plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))   
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title("final")
    plt.show()
```

Here's an example of the code working:
[input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKvpq.jpg), [output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqVnE.png), [input2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm8pr.jpg), [output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbFLG.png)

And not working:
[input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1boE5.jpg), [output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khq8d.jpg), [input2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR3zb.jpg), [output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gn9a.png)

This image shows a successful segmentation:
[image: success]
This image shows a failed segmentation:
[image: failure]

Comment: perhaps you can add constraints on the user? For example, if you don't find 4 corners at the 4 corners of the image, then show the user an error?

Comment: You should display the intermediate steps of the processing, to see what fails.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, intermediate processing steps are now shown in the edited post.

Comment: You see that the contrast on the left edge is insufficient, Canny fails to detect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the main issue here is that in the failing images, there is not a sufficient contrast between the paper and the table it's placed on. the ones that work it's basically white paper on dark background, so it's relatively easy to segment out the paper, however when you place the paper on a light colored surface, there isn't sufficient contrast between the paper and the background to tell what is what. Unfortunately in image processing, there is only so much you can do when your input image is bad so there is no easy automated fix for this but I can think of a few workarounds, but they're all going to require extra work.

One would be instead of having your program automatically detect where the paper is, just have a static box that the user has to place the document inside of and simply capture the contents that way. Probably the most simple to implement however it seems like you WANT to detect it automatically so this probably isn't what you're looking for.

Two would be to have some intermediate step allowing the user to select a specific threshold value to apply to the image. Basically you would take the picture, then have the user set a threshold value such that the paper ends up being white, and the background is dark, then you could use that as a template to create the boundary of the paper which you can then segment from the original image. This is probably the most work but closest to what you're looking for.

Three would be similar to number one but instead of having a set area you place the documents within, you could take the picture then have the user manually select where the corners are and segment it that way, more work than #1, less work than #2, but probably still not what you're looking for.

Finally you could just leave it as is and use it knowing that you need a sufficiently dark background for it to work correctly. There are probably some other work arounds but with a lot of image processing stuff you can be very constrained by the quality of your image and there isn't always a software solution for exactly what you're looking to do.

Comment: Basically I'll make a Telegram bot to replicate Camscanner so I can't  adopt neither the first nor the third suggestion, since the user will use the system camera app. I'll think about the second if I can't do any better. Thank you anyway!

Comment: okay ya that's kinda what I figured, basically if all you care about is black and white then having a user defined value for thresholding before you find the paper could work but if the paper and the background are VERY similar you could wind up with the same issue still... if you care about color i'd say do the same thing but use the found area as a template and impose it back on the original image so that you use the black and white to find your paper, then once you know where it is you can go back to the color picture with the location info. but all this work might not pay off on bad images